# Size of array that is not completely filled

Tags: c, arrays

I have written this code to take in values from a file convert them into binary and print out how many bits does its binary number has. But I get wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
FILE *p1;
p1=fopen("InputFile.txt","w");
int t=10,bin[30],i;
unsigned int a;
int *bi;
while(t--)
{
    printf("Enter a Number : ");
    scanf("%u",&a);
    fprintf(p1,"%u\n",a);
}
t=10;
fclose(p1);
p1=fopen("InputFile.txt","r");
while(t--)
{
    fscanf(p1,"%u",&a);
    for(i=0 ; a>0 ; a=a/2 , i++)
    {
        bin[i]=a%2;
    }
    for(i=size;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%d",bin[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(bin)/sizeof(int));
}

return 0;
}
```

This gives wrong output. Indeed it gives the maximum size of array.

I could print `i` as size of the binary number. But are there any predefined functions in calculating if how many values are passed into an array of large size?

Comment: No, it is up to you to keep track of how much of it you filled.

Answer (score 0):

No, SizeOf will always give you the total amount of memory allocated to a variable/memory structure. You must keep track of the amount of data you have written into the `bin[30]` array yourself. You could do this by keeping a counter and incrementing it inside your for loop:

```
for(i=0 ; a>0 ; a=a/2 , i++)
{
    bin[i]=a%2;
}
```